# Speculating about past events

Tags: grammar

Is it true that if we don't know what happened in the past we should make speculations using just *past simple*? (Even if the speculations are very unrealistic, for example abduction by aliens.)

For example George told us he would arrive today, but we don't know the exact time. We don't know what means of transportation he is using now. We can speculate:

> If he **took** the train he will be here in 5 hours.
>
> If he **took** the plain, he will be here in 1 hour.
>
> If he **was abducted** by aliens, he might be here in two years.

But then George's mother call us and says that her son took the train. Now we can't use *past simple*, we are obliged to use *past perfect*:

> If he **had taken** the plain, he would be here in one hour.
>
> If he **had been abducted** by aliens, he would ...

Comment: Yes, it's true. You said it! The action is completed (though *taking a train*) and thus, our all other guesses are in *perfect*.

Comment: Graduate, I believe your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anglophones often use our relatively small set of verb tenses/moods/etc. quite loosely (we've only really got ["past" and "not-past"](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/tense.htm), modified by various [modal/auxiliary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) verbs). So it's simply too broad a subject for me to cover all "past" tense, "did/didn't happen" usages here.

But OP's context specifically concerns the difference between referencing a past situation that might or might not have happened (*at time of speaking* it's unknown), as opposed to a "hypothetical irrealis past" (which in principle *could* have happened, but the speaker knows that actually it didn't).

> 1: *"If he **has** taken the plane he **will** be here soon"*  (speaker doesn't know what travel mode he used)
>    2: *"If he **had** taken the plane he **would** be here soon"* (speaker knows he *didn't* take the plane)

---

It's quite possible to use simple past *"If he **took** the train..."* in both those examples. In the case of...

> 1a: *"If he **took** the plane he **will** be here soon"*

...it's just a simpler alternative to #1 above, which I think would always have exactly the same meaning. Arguably the more complex verb form in #1 makes that meaning more "instantly accessible" to the audience - but both forms are perfectly valid, and are in common use,

But when we consider...

> 2a: *"If he **took** the plane he **would** be here soon"*

...it's no longer a fixed part of the meaning that *he didn't take the plane*. The speaker could say this to his wife while she's on the phone to their son, discussing whether the parents are willing to pay for their son to take a plane rather than a train (i.e. - even the *decision* about which travel mode to use hasn't yet been taken, so we're obviously not talking about a "past" event).

Comment: I think an American would be tend to say "If he took ..." whereas a British person would tend to say "If he has taken ..."